# Xamarin Forms - Native Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to experiment with Native Forms in XF. I have this in iOS working right. That is fine.

In Android, I am getting the following error:

'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'CreateSupportFragment' and the best extension method overload 'PageExtensions.CreateSupportFragment(ContentPage, Context)' requires a receiver of type 'ContentPage'

The code is erroring in the following code:

```
var _cp = new MainPage(); // my page from XF.
_list = _cp.CreateSupportFragment(this);
```

I have made sure that my nuget packages are up to date. I have cleaned and compiled. I've done a bunch of things, but alas, no love. Any ideas on this?

TIA

Comment: check this out https://blog.xamarin.com/native-forms-polished-shiny-xamarin-forms-2-5-0/

Comment: Thanks, however, I started from that blog post.  I am looking for why the error is occurring.  Is it due to some nuget package from xamarin that I have not included?  Their documentation on this is not the best.

Comment: Okay goodluck incase you find a solution do post it here

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you using Wallace B. McClure?

Answer (score 1):

you need add the line to head of source:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
```

because `CreateSupportFragment` is an extension method defined in it.